# Why does Chromecast v2 have Bluetooth and how do I connect with it?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, audio-streaming, chromecast

My Chromecast v2 shows up as an undefined Bluetooth device. Attempts to connect, however, have not been successful. This is most probably due to a secret pairing PIN.

Oddly, nowhere can I find documentation of this feature. Why wouldn't Google mention Bluetooth connectivity?

Can anyone explain what Chromecast uses Bluetooth for and how to connect with it? Eventually, I'd like to connect it with a Bluetooth audio receiver on my HiFi... (I know about external Bluetooth transmitters, I'd like to use the internal one, however, if possible.)

Answer (score 0):

That is for internal use, for example setup, etc and doesn't have any profiles that can be useful to developers, nor is intended to be used by developers.